# Streaming audio with getUserMedia, socketio, nodejs, redis

Tags: redis, socket.io, web-audio-api, getusermedia

I'm currently looking to use the onaudioprocess block of the Web Audio API/getUserMedia to 'stream' audio recording to the backend as the user is recording:

```
  // (socket call to 'recordInit' called when record button is clicked
  // not shown here)

  node.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
     [...]
     socket.emit('recordStream', {
       some_relevant_ids: '123abc',
       pcm_data: convertFloat32ToInt16(e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0))
     })
  }
```

I'm using socketio to emit to a nodejs/express backend:

```
var wstream = null;

socket.on('recordInit', function(data) {
  wstream = fs.createWriteStream(data.some_relevant_ids + '.pcm');
})

socket.on('recordStream', function(data) {
  wstream.write(data.pcm_data);
})

socket.on('recordStop', function(data) {
  // close the wstream, convert to mp3 using lame, send to CDN
})
```

When the user clicks a "Stop Recording" button, I emit a 'recordStop' request to the backend, which compiles all the pcm data that were sent, converts it to MP3, and sends the completed product off to a CDN.

I've gotten the whole thing to work well for a single user by using a file handle (wstream) as a global variable, but I'm looking to make this work for multiple simultaneous users now, so I can't use the one common variable for the file handle. I'm also concerned that the socket requests to recordStream might not be in the correct order, and perhaps I'll need to send in a timestamp (via the frontend) and sort the recordStream packets at the end based on the timestamp.

TL;DR: I'm wondering:

- What's the best way to do this (storing packets of PCM data with a timestamp attached to it and compiling it together at the end)? I'm currently thinking of putting it into Redis during the streaming, and then retrieving it all at the end in order based on the timestamp. I'm not sure if this would be best practice or not for something like Redis.
- I tried experimenting with just opening a new wstream handle inside every recordStream based on the 'some_relevant_ids' name, which I pass in in every request. However, while a lot of PCM data was written to the file, upon converting it to an MP3, it wasn't a valid audio file. I'm not really sure why that didn't work.

If anyone has any ideas on this one please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can find my implementation of `.wav` to opus packet compression on client and back to `.wav` on server side [**here**](https://github.com/mido22/recordOpus), you get the option of saving recording in `mp3` and `wav` formats also, but of course, you would need `ffmpeg` installed in server.